# Renaming a Html File based upon content from within the file by using a Batch File

Tags: html, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I need a batch file that reads a line of text within an html file and then will rename that file name based on what it finds.

I have a large number of html files where their file names are just numbers.html (2345.html)for example.

Within each of the html files is a line that roughly looks like the following; example 1 - `<span class="term-name">fed up</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;`

example 2 - `<span class="term-name">ventilating</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;`

How can I possibly get the batch file to find the line containing `<span class="term-name">` and then rename the file to the words that is after and before `</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

In my above example it would make a file called ventilating.txt and another file called fed up.txt

I have an example of where it can find a line in the file like Description=Mike and then produces a file called Mike.txt. (see the .bat below)

But I cannot work out how to select the words from my above examples.

```
    @echo off

for %%i in (%1) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%j in ('findstr /B /I "Description=" "%%i"') do (
    ren "%%i" "%%j.temp_txt"
  )
)

ren *.temp_txt *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try command:

```
findstr /c:"<span class=\"term-name\">ventilating</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;" file.html`
```

Which means find string `<span class=\"term-name\">ventilating</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;` in file `file.html` and of course you can find any string you want. The output should be the matching line if this command finish successfully. You can then parse the word `ventilating` by command:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3* delims=><" %a in (%t%) do echo %a`
```

Where `%t%` contains the matching line output by first command and `%a` is the word you want.

Finally, the command should as following:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,3* delims=><" %a in (`findstr /c:"<span class=\"term-name\">ventilating</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;" file.html`) do @echo %a`
```

And you will get the word in console. Of course you can rename your file by:

```
rename file.html %a.html
```

Additionally, if these commands will be used in script, single `%` should be replaced by double `%` as `%%a`.

Please let me know if any question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is a `HTML Parser` usable from the command line (and so in bash scripts).

For example, you can take a look at [GitHub - ericchiang/pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) which is a `cli HTML Parser`.

You can use this tool with your example, like this :

```
$ cat numbers.html | pup 'span.term-name text{}'
```

More information about it in the [README.md](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing:

- the HTML file or a file pattern is given as a command line argument;
- there is only one tag `<span>` in the matching line;
- the closing `</span>` tag is in the same line as the related opening tag;
- the value of attribute `class` does not contain `<` or `>` characters;
- the first matching line of each processed file is to be taken;
- the file(s) can be treated in a case-insensitive manner;

the following code should work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%I in ("%~1") do (
    set "LINE="
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ('
        findstr /I /R /C:"<span  *class=[^<>]*>..*</span>" "%%~fI"
    ') do (
        if not defined LINE (
            set "LINE=%%J"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "LINE=!LINE:*<span =!"
            for /F "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%K in ("!LINE!") do (
                endlocal
                ECHO ren "%%~fI" "%%K%%~xI"
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

This script returns the `ren` command line to the console for testing purposes. To actually rename any files, remove the upper-case `ECHO` command.